# Laravel API Passport - Authenticating user and redirect to dashboard

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport

I have laravel passport set up, and a API function which authenticates a user based on user_id, which works great. I can return user data after logging them in accessing the API through cURL. However, I don't just want to return user data, I want to redirect to dashboard. So this function can login any user and redirect them logged in to the dashboard.

Whenever I add a redirect in the API function, when calling the API it simply redirects to the login page thinking the user is not logged in. Losing session or something? Wondering if anyone can shed some light on this.

Comment: API responses are stateless, you can't perform a redirect from an API endpoint, you'll have to add some javascript on your front end to redirect on an appropriate response.

Comment: OK... so I removed the redirect from the API, and instead inserted it in the cURL function accessing the API. The same thing happens though, the system does not understand the user is logged in